# Any API to search a list of domain names?

Tags: api, dns, domain-name

Assume there is a list of domain names but you dont know whether they are taken by someone else. Assume that the list is too big that you dont want to manually type in each word and see if the domain name is available or not. How would you get around this issue? Is there a public API by a company that we can use in our program and see the availability of names based on, say, the return value of a method call? If there is, I'd appreciate code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is a [whois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) on the domain. This will tell you if its registered and with which registrar. There are many ways to issue the whois, [via a command line](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whois), [via PHP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Whois/), [via a web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817/who-provides-a-whois-api).